# how to count subscriptions in laravel-cashier

Tags: laravel-cashier

I've got subscriptions working in Laravel-Cashier. Now I'd like to be able to see how many of my users have subscribed. The [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/billing#checking-subscription-status) say to use `Subscription::query()->active();`, but this gives me an error - `Class "Subscription" not found.`

I don't have a Subscription class, but there is a subscription table used by Cashier. I could create a class based on that table, but I'm concerned that will mess up Cashier's own logic (surely Cashier has Subscription class I can't access). I'm also not convinced it will provide the correct information since it may count past subscriptions.

`$user->subscribed('default')` correctly returns the subscription status of an individual user, but `User::all()->subscribed('default')` returns an error `BadMethodCallException  Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::subscribed does not exist.`

I tried creating my own method in User as follows:

```
public function paid()
    {
        return $this->subscribed('default');
    }
```

This has the same problem that I can use it on an individual user, but not on a collection.

I could loop through all my users and check individually, but that feels like overkill. Surely there's a way to simply publish Cashier's Subscription class so that I can run the command they suggest - `Subscription::query()->active();`

Or is there a way of running subscribed/paid on a collection that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to access the Subscription model by adding

```
use Laravel\Cashier\Subscription;
```

to the controller file.